# PySide File Monitoring

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I am making a application in PySide. I want to incorporate a feature where certain files can be monitored for changes (such as log files).  When the contents of the file have been changed, it should update in the program.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Well, this is a comment because I'm not sure how to do it in PySide, but in C++ you can use http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qfilesystemwatcher.html which I'm sure it's somewhere in PySide too.

Comment: It's also wrapped in PySide so you can use it: [QFileSystemWatcher](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QFileSystemWatcher.html)